# MATLAB: Is there any way for two reshape to cancel each other and two permute to each other

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 3 by 3 complex matrix `c` such that I have to do the following operations. `c` is in general complex, `c` can also be larger but it is a square matrix.

```
   c= rand(3,3)   
    A = bsxfun(@mtimes,permute(reshape(reshape(permute(c(:,1:end~=2)',[2 1]),1,3*2).', 3, []),[3,1,2]),c(:,1))
    conj(permute(A,[2 1 3]))
```

However, times take too long for this. Which part is the most time-consuming?

First of all, `c(:,1:end~=2)'` is a complex conjugate transpose of the matrix without the 2nd columns.

```
c = rand(3,3)
c =
    0.9791    0.2003    0.9764
    0.5933    0.2570    0.4920
    0.5811    0.6384    0.9031

c(:,1:end~=2)'
ans =
    0.9791    0.5933    0.5811
    0.9764    0.4920    0.9031
```

Second, `permute(c(:,1:end~=2)',[2 1])` is a trick to make the reshape works row-wise.

```
permute(c(:,1:end~=2)',[2 1])
ans =
    0.9791    0.9764
    0.5933    0.4920
    0.5811    0.9031
```

Third, do the reshape and `.'` to make it a column:

```
reshape(permute(c(:,1:end~=2)',[2 1]),1,3*2).'
ans =
    0.9791
    0.5933
    0.5811
    0.9764
    0.4920
    0.9031
```

Fourth, reshape the column to a 2 by 3 matrix:

```
reshape(reshape(permute(c(:,1:end~=2)',[2 1]),1,3*2).', 3, [])
ans =
    0.9791    0.9764
    0.5933    0.4920
    0.5811    0.9031
```

Fifth, create a multidimensional array with each layer being a row vector of the column (just reordering, not complex conjugation is taken).

```
permute(reshape(reshape(permute(c(:,1:end~=2)',[2 1]),1,3*2).', 3, []),[3,1,2])
ans(:,:,1) =
    0.9791    0.5933    0.5811
ans(:,:,2) =
    0.9764    0.4920    0.9031
```

Sixth, use bsxfun to get the outer product of first column of `c` with each layer

```
bsxfun(@mtimes,permute(reshape(reshape(permute(c(:,1:end~=2)',[2 1]),1,3*2).', 3, []),[3,1,2]),c(:,1))
ans(:,:,1) =
    0.9587    0.5809    0.5689
    0.5809    0.3520    0.3448
    0.5689    0.3448    0.3376
ans(:,:,2) =
    0.9560    0.4817    0.8843
    0.5793    0.2919    0.5359
    0.5673    0.2859    0.5248
```

The last I don't think can be simplified. Its purpose is to take the complex conjugate of matrix at each layer:

```
A = bsxfun(@mtimes,permute(reshape(reshape(permute(c(:,1:end~=2)',[2 1]),1,3*2).', 3, []),[3,1,2]),c(:,1))
A(:,:,1) =
    0.9587    0.5809    0.5689
    0.5809    0.3520    0.3448
    0.5689    0.3448    0.3376
A(:,:,2) =
    0.9560    0.4817    0.8843
    0.5793    0.2919    0.5359
    0.5673    0.2859    0.5248

conj(permute(A,[2 1 3]))
ans(:,:,1) =
    0.9587    0.5809    0.5689
    0.5809    0.3520    0.3448
    0.5689    0.3448    0.3376
ans(:,:,2) =
    0.9560    0.5793    0.5673
    0.4817    0.2919    0.2859
    0.8843    0.5359    0.5248
```

`A(:,:,1)` is symmetric by coincidence.

Comment: What takes the most time in your code is printing to the command window because your statements are not terminated with `;`. (I am not joking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly:

- Two consecutive `reshape` operations don't necessarily "cancel" out, be can be replaced with just the outer-most `reshape` (see more info below).
- As far as the `permute` operations, you just need to determine if you actually need them (again more info below).

---

**Detailed Response:**

You have a ton of redundant and unnecessary steps. Here I've outlined a few and presented an alternate solution that is undoubtedly going to be faster. As a side note, it is very beneficial to step through your code and make sure that you understand all pieces before just pasting together a bunch of different things without truly knowing what they each do.

1. You don't need to use the logical comparison `1:end~=2`, just simply specify all indices except `2`

   ```
   without_column_2 = c(:,[1 3:end])
   ```
2. `permute(a', [2 1])` is completely unnecessary because you are taking the complex conjugate transpose of something (using `'`) and then instantly taking the transpose again (this time using `permute`) which results in the original matrix. Just replace this with whatever `a` was. In your case this is simply `conj(c(:,[1 3:end]))`
3. Two `reshapes` in a row is *never* necessary. The way you have it written you first reshape to a row vector then take the transpose (which is technically *another* `reshape`) to make it a column vector and then reshape to a 3 x N. Just skip the first two steps and go straight to the 3 x N.

   ```
   reshape(c(:,[1 3:end]), 3, []);
   ```

   That being said, if you actually look closely at this **your original data was already this shape** so you don't need *any* reshapes. If you actually need the complex conjugate (since you obviously don't need the transpose part), you can use `conj` to get that.

For those keeping score, that means we've now simplified:

```
reshape(reshape(permute(c(:,1:end~=2)',[2 1]),1,3*2).', 3, [])
```

To

```
conj(c(:,[1 3:end]))
```

Now to get this so that each column of `c` is along the second dimension you used a `permute`; however this is just a simple `reshape` operation

```
reshape(conj(c(:,[1 3:end])), 1, size(c, 1), [])
```

Now you have to take that outer product with `c(:,1)` and conjugate transpose the result.

That would simplify to:

```
out = conj(permute(bsxfun(@mtimes, reshape(conj(c(:,[1 3:end])), 1, size(c, 1), []), c(:,1)), [2 1 3]));
```

After all of that though, why does this need to be stuck on one line? It really makes it extremely illegible and will likely confuse anyone looking at this code after you. You'd be much better off breaking it into multiple lines so that the logic is easier to follow.

Answer (score 2):

You asked which part was the most time consuming, so I'll discuss how to find that out:

The first thing we do is rearrange your "1-liner" code into single operations as follows (note that I explicitly put `transpose` and `ctranspose` instead of `.'` and `'`, respectively):

```
function q39156646
c = rand(3)+1i*rand(3); % Changed this slightly to represent the problem better.
A = bsxfun(@mtimes,...
      permute(...
        reshape(...
          transpose(...
            reshape(...
              permute(...
                ctranspose(...
                  c(:,1:end~=2)...
                  ),...
                [2 1]),...
              1,3*2)...
            ),...
          3, []),...
        [3,1,2]),...
      c(:,1));
conj(permute(A,[2 1 3]));
```

Then, we run the profiler and get:

[image: Profiler output]

Therefore: **Indexing `c` takes the most time** (though it is difficult to say exactly by how much as percentages, but not order, vary quite a lot due to the low overall runtimes).